Which sentence is the most correct?


He looks like the hottest thing ever.
He looks the hottest thing ever.


Which one is the most correct?

Perhaps better way  to say it, would be: “He is the hottest-looking person [ever].“ = He is very attractive in a sexual way.

Did you find this sentence or did you create it yourself? If it's the latter consider replacing "thing" with man or guy. See the hyperbolic title of [He is] The sexiest man alive Note that the men are nearly all actors, and the majority come from the USA. Talk about discrimination!

@Mari-LouA I think there might be a misunderstanding here based on US/UK usage differences! The sentence (I'm assuming) is supposed to be a (colloquial) US idiom meaning that someone looks "cool," "trendy," or like "a big deal." It isn't necessarily a reference to romantic appeal at all - even though the adjective "hot," on its own, does usually convey that sense when used to describe a person. But, being part of the expression "hottest thing ever" can change that - and it isn't literally calling the person a "thing," either. Compare https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hot%20stuff

@QuackE.Duck I remember a hit in the 1970s by Hot Chocolate, a British band, titled "You sexy thing" so, in slang thing can refer to inanimate objects and people, but the question boils down to: HE LOOKS LIKE + Noun/NP... vs HE LOOKS + Noun(NP).

The meaning and the tone is very casual.  Both are correct grammar, and at this level of informallity the "most correct" doesn't matter.  You won't be using this kind of language in a school essay or a business letter. In slang, different people will talk differently and there is no "most correct".  I've voted to close as "more correct" doesn't make sense as a question here.

Both of the alternatives in your question are grammatically valid sentences. However, if you are being asked to choose one as being the better or more correct option, and the context is what would be suitable for general/casual conversation, you should choose the one with the word "like."
This is because there is a difference in register associated with the different grammatical constructions used in the two sentences. The first version,

He looks like the hottest thing ever.

is a simple simile, which is a very common way of expressing comparison or similarity, and so is not 'marked': i.e, it doesn't draw attention to itself by sounding stilted, awkward, or overly formal. In other words, it sounds more natural than the alternative without the word "like":

He looks the hottest thing ever.

This second version is less preferable in a general, conversational context, because it sounds somewhat "stiff" and overly formal. Within the sentence itself, there is a (slight) conflict of registers -- between the informality of the expression "hottest thing ever" and the formality of the grammatical construction employed. (The construction is subject looks [to be] predicate, where the infinitive "to be" is elided.)
The conflict of registers within the second alternative is the clue that you shouldn't choose it, and should instead stick to the first version, which uses "like."

"He looks the hottest thing ever" is formal?? How is the copular verb "looks" formal in this instance when the person is described as being the "hottest"?

33 hits for looks like the hottest thing that shrinks to two hits if we add the pronoun he...


He looks hot OK 2. He look like hot NO 3. He looks the hottest person OK 4. He looks like the hottest person [in the world] OK


@Mari-LouA Again, there may be a usage difference here: I'm in the US and think the omitted infinitive construction sounds formal, but maybe it's more common elsewhere? I did an Ngrams search replacing "hottest thing ever" with "big deal" (since that seems like it would have more total results) but keeping the same grammatical comparison. Here is the result: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seems+like+a+big+deal%2Cseems+a+big+deal&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3. Then, I went to the page of book results for 2021-2022 for the version without "like." The top 3

are 2 from the UK, one from Canada. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22seems%20a%20big%20deal%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2021,cd_max:2022&lr=lang_en

I realize this isn't the most precise metric, and now I'm curious as to how significant the difference actually is :)

Also, I should have mentioned it only seems "formal" to me when the predicate is a noun phrase, not an adjective. "He looks hot" does not seem formal at all!

"He looks the hottest thing ever" …because it sounds somewhat "stiff" and overly formal. I disagree. Meanwhile seems like a big deal and/or … seems like the biggest deal ever … are both informal. I don't have a problem with either. The versions sound better with "like".

@Mari-LouA Maybe we just have different opinions on how formal (or not) OP's sentence alternatives sound, then. In that case, if there isn't a clear-cut answer, maybe the issue is with the assignment (probably some kind of multiple-choice quiz?) that OP's question came from? If it isn't supposed to be testing awareness of 'register,' then I have no idea which option is supposed to be 'more correct,' since as you said there is no grammatical problem with either.
